# Issue related to 'exist'

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am designing an automation framework for a web based application. I have used 'Exist' method to check if the user has correctly logged into the application. Something like this:

```
If  Browser("XXX").Page("YYY").WebElement("Either you have entered").Exist(0)
Then                 
    Browser("XXX").Page("YYY").Image("btnok").Click
    fnReset = false
Else
    If  Browser("XXX").Page("YYY").WebElement("Account Search").Exist(0) Then
        fnReset = true
    End If
    Browser("XXX").Page("YYY").Sync
End If
```

This code works fine , if an invalid username/password is entered as it hits the `IF` part first.

However, when I try with a valid username/password, the `IF` condition step keeps running for a long time and the `ELSE` part is not getting executed at all.

Is there an issue with the timing for which the test waits or is there any other problem?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that the `"Either you have entered"` exists even when the login succeeds but isn't visible to the user? Perhaps it has `hidden=true`. Try to login successfully manually and then highlight that `WebElement` from the Object Repository. If it doesn't complain that the object does not exist the condition you're using for detecting successful login isn't correct.